# Loading image with data uri as source doesnt work in safari

Tags: html, image, safari, data-uri

Loading image with data uri as source doesnt work in safari.
I am using the following source value see: http://jsfiddle.net/VnnhS/

```
<img src='data...'/>
```

everything is working with chrome IE and FF.
could it be size limitation?

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't normal because [here](http://caniuse.com/datauri) says that Safari supports it, so I don't know what is your problem, can you send a screenshot?